# Compare two object key values, return minimum denominator

Tags: web

I am new to NodeJS coming from Python and having trouble with this practice problem.

Given two objects (key, value pairs) return the minimum denominator between them.

```
ObjectA = {"A": 10, "B": 20, "C": 30} "Stock"
ObjectB = {"A": 5, "B": 10, "C": 1} "Per Item"
```

`function(objectA, objectB)` would return 2 since `ObjectB` can go into `ObjectA` "fully" 2 times.

In my mind or Python, I would for loop each key/value compare the two objects. Not sure how to do this in a performance way/deal with it if key-values are out of order.

Unsure how to iterate through these objects in JavaScript, would I have to call each child independently? How do I index them?

main.js:

```
function howMany(params) {
  const {objectA, objectB} = params
  Object.keys(objectA).reduce((denominator, key) => {
    if(objectB[key] === undefined) {
      return 0;
    }
    const d = Math.floor(objectA[key] / objectB[key]);

    return d < denominator ? d : denominator;
  }, Infinity);
}

module.exports = {howMany}

var params = require('./inputs.js');
howMany(params.returnsOne);
console.log(howMany(params.returnsOne));
```

inputs.js:

```
module.exports = {
  returnsOne: {
    objectA: {
      a: 10,
      b: 5,
      c: 5
    },
    objectB: {
      a: 20,
      b: 10,
      c: 5
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know ahead of time that both objects have the exact same set of keys? If not, what is the desired behavior when a key is missing from one of the objects?

Comment: _"would return 2 since `ObjectB` can go into `ObjectA` "fully" 2 times."_ What is the definition of "fully"? Property `"C"` at `ObjectB` is thirty times less than property `"C"` at `ObjectA`, why would `2` be the expected return value from an evaluation of the object values.

Comment: There is nothing about that in the prompt but I would assume if a key is missing, then it would return 0? since you could not fulfill the requirements

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry I should clarify since Object B[A] goes into ObjectA[A] 2 times, B -> 2 times, c->30 times,  but since A/B only go into it two times, it returns two. It's supposed to be for "like a recipe and your refrigerator" scenario

Comment: The code you posted at the end should return 0, because the second value for a is greater than the first, and so it cannot fit even once. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Maybe I have something backwards but intended return is 1. since ObjectA[a, b, c] goes into ObjectB[a,b,c], minimum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the spread syntax to pass all the ratios to `Math.min` and then truncate the result:

```js
var objectA = { A: 10, B: 20, C: 30 },
    objectB = { A: 5, B: 10, C: 1 },
    denominator = Math.floor(Math.min(...Object.keys(objectA).map( 
                                         key => objectA[key] / objectB[key] ))) || 0;
    
console.log(denominator);
```

More integrated with what you have as context:

```js
function howMany({objectA, objectB}) {
    return Math.floor(Math.min(...Object.keys(objectA).map( 
                                         key => objectA[key] / objectB[key] ))) || 0;
}
const params = {
  returnsOne: {
    objectA: { A: 10, B: 20, C: 30 },
    objectB: { A: 5, B: 10, C: 1 }
  }
};
console.log(howMany(params.returnsOne));
```

Comment: Nice answer. Add a `|| 0` to handle the missing key case.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what should be the return value when a key is missing. It seems to me that this is undefined. Currently, this code then returns `NaN`. Alternatives would be 0 (as if the missing value defaults to `Infinity`), `Infinity` (as if the missing value defaults to 0), `undefined`, `null`. It all depends on what the OP expects to get in this scenario.

Comment: I went with this OP comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748952/compare-two-object-key-values-return-minimum-denominator/46749063#comment80444113_46748952 - he suggested 0 as a return value when a key is missing.

Comment: Ah, I missed that! Done as you suggested.

Comment: I can't seem to get it work under my function (in my edit) but I like your "one-liner" solution haha. Any tips for learning JS? Seems like I'm out of my element based on the responses and my capabilities (a: @OriDrori too)

Comment: I added a version of the code that is more in line with the code you presented at the end of your question. You learn by doing. In fact, trying to answer questions on SO, and looking up things as you try to do so, is a great way to learn. Of course, you'll often come to conclusions that others will have posted before you, but that does not matter, it is the joy of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of ObjectA with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and on each iteration assign the denominator to the current lowest, or to 0 if key is missing in ObjectB:

```js
const ObjectA = {"A": 10, "B": 20, "C": 30};
const ObjectB = {"A": 5, "B": 10, "C": 1};

const findBinA = (objectA, objectB) => Object.keys(objectA)
  .reduce((denominator, key) => {
    const d = Math.floor(objectA[key] / objectB[key]) || 0;

    return d < denominator ? d : denominator;
  }, Infinity);

console.log(findBinA(ObjectA, ObjectB));
```

Comment: How can I refactor it similar to my outline?

function howMany(params) {
    const {objectA, objectB} = params
  }
  
var params =   returnsOne: {
    objectA: {
      "A": 10,
      "B": 5,
      "C": 5
    },
    objectB: {
      "A": 20,
      "B": 10,
      "C": 5
    }
  }

Comment: What part of your outline have I missed?

Comment: JavaScript syntax confuses me, sorry pressed enter a bit early there.

Comment: Since you have always 2 params, you don't need to get a list of params, and then destructure them to individual variables.

Comment: could you look at my edit and see what i did wrong, im getting undefined as a return value expecting 1

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the keys and take the one with the smalles value of the division.

```js
var objectA = { A: 10, B: 20, C: 30 },
    objectB = { A: 5, B: 10, C: 1 },
    keys = Object.keys(objectA),
    key = keys.reduce(function (a, b) {
        var aa = Math.floor(objectA[a] / objectB[a]),
            bb = Math.floor(objectA[b] / objectB[b]);
        return aa < bb ? a : b;
    }),
    denominator = Math.floor(objectA[key] / objectB[key]);
    
console.log(denominator);
```